# Handling > 4K data in cookies

Tags: cookies, limit

I have recently implemented a shopping cart like functionality that works like a charm except for the fact that I am using a cookie for storing selected items and cannot add too many of them without exceeding the 4K max. cookie size.

I am now considering using a dynamic list of indexed cookies to increase the space. Does this approach sound right or is there a better way of doing this?

On a side note, I am storing JSON data in the cookie for easier serialization/deserialization but am wondering if I should drop JSON to maximize the useful data stored in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use the data on client side only, you should consider to use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). Those services are supported by all modern browsers. As a side effect the data is not send to your server with every request.

If you need to access all the data on the server as well, I would suggest to store them in a database and create a key for the dataset. You could then just store the key inside your cookie and request the actual data if needed at the client.